# Extracting values from more than one key in a list of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of `dict`s:

```
ld=[{'key1': 1, 'key2':2, 'key3':3},{'key1': 4, 'key2':5, 'key3':6}]
```

I know to select values from 1 key would be

```
[sub['key2'] for sub in ld ]
```

returning

```
[2, 5]
```

How would I select values for key2 and key3 returning?

```
[[2,3], [5,6]]
```

I know that I could also remove key1 but in my real case I am selecting 2 out of 20 keys so I do not want to remove 18 keys.

Comment: As a list comprehension: `[[sub['key2'], sub['key3']] for sub in ld ]`

Comment: ahhh.   thank you.  I tried sub[['key2', 'key3']]

Comment: The `itemgetter` class from the built-in `operator` module would be useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work

```
ld = [{'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}, {'key1': 4, 'key2': 5, 'key3': 6}]
output = [[x['key2'], x['key3']] for x in ld]
print(output)
```

output

```
[[2, 3], [5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do nested list comprehensions

```
[[sub[k] for k in keys] for sub in ld]
```

where `keys` is the list of keys you want to extract, e.g. `["key1", "key2"]`.

---

Full example:

```py
>>> ld = [{"key1": 1, "key2": 2, "key3": 3}, {"key1": 4, "key2": 5, "key3": 6}]
>>> keys = ["key2", "key3"]
>>> print([[sub[k] for k in keys] for sub in ld])
[[2, 3], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: and this answers my next question which was how can I write a function that extracts the values with a list of keys as a parameter.  thanks Holt

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a list literal to produce a list with both items for each `sub`.

`[ [sub['key2'], sub['key3']] for sub in ld ]`

Result:

`[[2, 3], [5, 6]]`

Answer (score 0):

Method1

```py
ld=[
        {'key1': 1, 'key2':2, 'key3':3},
        {'key1': 4, 'key2':5, 'key3':6}
    ] 

wanted = ['key2', 'key3']

output = []
for i in wanted:
    output.append([d[i] for d in ld])
    
print(output) # [[2,3], [5,6]]
```

Method2

```py
ld = [
    {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3},
    {'key1': 4, 'key2': 5, 'key3': 6}
]


output = []
for i in ld:
    temp = []
    for k, v in i.items():
        if k in ['key2', 'key3']:
            temp.append(v)
    output.append(temp)

print(output)  # [[2,3], [5,6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like that ?

```
ld=[{'key1': 1, 'key2':2, 'key3':3},{'key1': 4, 'key2':5, 'key3':6}] 
new_list = []
for i in ld:
    k = []
    k.append(i['key2'])
    k.append(i['key3'])
    new_list.append(k)
```